# AJAX + jQuery + Datatables plugin - add custom column to requested ajax data?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatables

I am pulling data via AJAX / PHP into a table and want to display the data via the DataTable JS plugin. The data query works well, but now I would like to add one more column for each record containing several buttons that would allow the user to preview / edit / delete the respective record.

I seem to be unable to append the additional column data containing the html code for the buttons to data table array, respectively DataTable is throwing an error message saying that the received json data is not properly formatted. This must be referring to the html code of the buttons as it works fine when pulling data without the extra column.

Below my code:

Mysqli query:

```
$result = $db->query($sql) or die(mysqli_error($db));       

if($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // return total number of rows for pagination
    $totalData = $result->num_rows;
    $totalFiltered = $totalData;

    // return table data - MUST BE NON-ASSOCIATIVE ARRAY
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $data[] = array(
            $row['ID'],
            $row['Holidex'],
            $row['First'],
            $row['Last'],
            $row['Email'],
            "Button" => "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-primary btn-xs\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#EditEmailModal\" data-keyboard=\"true\" data-id=\"".$row['ID']."\"><i class=\"fa fa-edit\"></i></button> <button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-danger btn-xs\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#EditEmailModal\" data-keyboard=\"true\" data-id=\"".$row['ID']."\"><i class=\"fa fa-times\"></i></button>",
        );
    }

    // finalize array with elements required by DataTable plugin
    $json_data = array(
      "recordsTotal"    => intval( $totalData ),        // total number of records
      "recordsFiltered" => intval( $totalFiltered ),    // total number of records after searching, if there is no searching then totalFiltered = totalData
      "success"         => true,                        // must have a success message (false / true)
      "aaData"          => $data                        // table data as array
    );

    echo json_encode($json_data);
}
```

I tried replacing the double quotes `"` with single quotes `'` and to remove the escape backslashes `\` without success. What else can I do?

Thanks,
A2k

UPDATE:
updated my JS accordingly to have buttons generated after the server-side procedure is done, but I am unable to attach the `data.ID` value to the button `data-*` element. I tried using both `data` and `aaData` when refering to the ID column, how come its not picking up the value?

UPDATE2:
Edited the JS code to reflect latest changes

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="init">                  
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#auto_cc_table').DataTable( {
            // load table data via AJAX
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax":{
                url: "../../plugins/MySQL/ajax_action.php", // json datasource
                data: { action:"view_auto_cc_email_AJAX" },
                type: "post",  // connection method (default: GET)
            },
            "columns": [
                { "aaData": "ID" },
                { "aaData": "Holidex" },
                { "aaData": "First" },
                { "aaData": "Last" },
                { "aaData": "Email" },
                { "aaData": null },
            ],
            columnDefs: [{
                className: "text-right", "targets": [1],
                className: "text-nowrap", "targets": [3],

                // puts a button in the last column
                targets: [-1], render: function (a, b, data, d) {

                //console.log(data);        // error - undefinded in console
                console.log(row);           // ok
                console.log(row.ID);        // error - undefined in console
                //console.log(row.Holidex); // error - undefined in console
                //console.log(row.First);       // error - undefined in console
                //console.log(row.Last);        // error - undefined in console
                //console.log(row.Email);       // error - undefined in console

                    return '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#EditEmailModal" data-keyboard="true" data-id="'+ data.ID +'"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button> '
                    +'<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#EditEmailModal" data-keyboard="true" data-id="'+ data.ID +'"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>'
                },
            }],
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            stateSave: true,
            buttons: [
              'copyHtml5',
              'excelHtml5',
              'csvHtml5',
              'pdfHtml5',
              {
                extend: 'print',
                message: '(c) Copyright'
              },
              {
              extend: 'collection',
              text: 'Others',
              buttons: [
                {
                  text: 'Toggle button',
                  action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
                  dt.column( -6 ).visible( ! dt.column( -6 ).visible() );
                  }
                },
                'colvis',
                'columnsToggle',
              ]
              },
            ],
            "pagingType": "full_numbers",
            "pageLength": 25,
            "lengthChange": true,
            "searching": true,
            "ordering": false,
            "order": [[ 1, "asc" ], [ 2, "asc" ]],
            "info": true,
            "autoWidth": true
        })
    });
</script>
```

UPDATE 3:
Following the solution below, I updated the JS code above to narrow down the console log issues, learning that `console.log(data)` and `console.log(row.ID)` result in `undefined` in the JS console, while `console.log(row)` returns the full row data eg. `7,ADMIN,John, Doe,john.doe@gmail.com`.

Since I cant get the `ID` of the specific row via `row.ID`, I am now playing around with `.split()` to obtain the first left comma separated value, but this is nothing more but a monkeypatch for something that shouldnt be in the first place...

Note: `var rowData = $('#auto_cc_table').DataTable().rows(btnRow).data()[0];` does return the full row data as shown above.

Modal Call:

```
// DISPLAY EMAIL RECORD
$('#EditEmailModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {

      var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
      var btnRow = button.closest("tr");
      var rowData = $('#auto_cc_table').DataTable().rows(btnRow).data()[0];
      var rowData1 = rowData + '';
      var rowData2 = rowData1.split(",");

      alert("RowData: " + rowData2);
});
```

Comment: Why are you trying to add the buttons to your data set?  You should be adding it through the columnDefs  render  options

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are trying to do is create buttons server side and send them through as part of your ajax.  What you should be doing is create the buttons as part of your DataTable definition. That would look something like this:

Instead of using the data-id, here is an event handler that lets you get to the whole row's data. http://jsbin.com/viqafe/edit?html,js,output modified to do this.

```
// button click event handler

$('#EditEmailModal').on('show.bs.modal',function (event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
    var btnRow = button.closest("tr");
    var rowData = $('#example').DataTable().rows(btnRow).data()[0];

     // process the data here
 });


            var table = $('#yourTable').DataTable({
                "data": yourDataObject,
                // because your data is in arrays, not objects the column defs have to be changed
                "columns": [
                { "name": "ID" },
                { "name": "Holidex" },
                { "name": "First" },
                { "name": "Last" },
                { "name": "Email" },
                { "name": "Buttons"},
                ],
                columnDefs: [{
                    // puts a button in the last column
                    targets: [-1], render: function (data, type, row, meta) {

                       // your id is in the first cell if the inner array so
                           var ID = row[0];

                            // look at your console and make sure there is a value here.
                            console.log(ID);

                           console.log(row);


                            return '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#EditEmailModal" data-keyboard="true" data-id="' + ID +'"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>' 
                                   +'<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#EditEmailModal" data-keyboard="true" data-id="' + ID +'"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>'
                    }
                }],

            });

        });
```

Comment: thanks for that. The code seems to be working, but I am unable to attach the `data.ID` value to the button. Any chance you can help have a look? Thanks

Comment: ID is based on your column definition above.   I added some console.logs so you can check the log to make sure ID is a valid data object name. It is case sensitive

Comment: 'ID' is correct, that's the actual column name and syntax used throughout the code... Chrome debugger shoes that the button HTML is undefined.

Comment: I ran the bottom logic here http://jsbin.com/viqafe/edit?html,js,output  in chrome.  The buttons showed up as expected

Comment: I tried that and the buttons show up as expected. As mentioned earlier, the problem seems to be that the value of column `ID` is not being defined / returned. I looked at your JS bin and dont really know what to do with it as the syntax is entirely different to what I am doing with my AJAX data. You can see the updated code above.

Comment: had a closer look at your bin sample and found that all `data-id` elements are also undefined, reflecting the same problem as I have.

Comment: I added a console.log for row.ID to make sure it is valid. I also added an event handler that gets the data for the row differently than using the data-id.

Comment: Really appreciate the effort. I fiddled around with the console and found that only `console.log(row)` results in the return of data. all other combinations `data / row.ID / row.Email` end up as undefined and I cant figure out why...

Comment: Either way, I managed to extract the ID value during the modal call via `split()` since your code returns the complete row data instead of only the first column data. I have no idea why, but the fact that `row.ID` is not working seems to be the main issue here -.- Thanks for all your help.

Comment: I am curious on what you are splitting on.  It almost makes it sound like the data is still serialized.

Comment: this is the output of `console.log(row);` : `["7", "ADMIN", "Jane", "Doe", "jane.doe@gmail.com"]`. Splitting is done in form of `.split("["7", "ADMIN", "Jane", "Doe", "jane.doe@gmail.com"]",",")[0]` to get the ID. I am thinking there might be a problem when handing data `aaData` back over to the table...?

Comment: I see your issue.   Your date is just an array of arrays. There is no object so there is no id.

Comment: so how do I change an array to an object? jQuery `$.extend({}, ["7", "ADMIN", "Jane", "Doe", "jane.doe@gmail.com"]);` or can I address this during my mysql interaction already?
`

Comment: You can leave the data the way it is, just address it by its position instead of its name. I updated the logic above to reflect that.

Comment: it works nice for me too (+1) i  have a one question that i have a Sr. column as a first column so how can i display that column as  first in td n i m using angular so i display Sr. as a $index + 1 Thanks in Advance :)